# Filtering Azure Active Directory Groups

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, command, powerpoint

I want to  get all the groups from azure AD where the  group name contains 'Glorea'.

Any one knows the azure ad command?

Please post here

Regards
Akhil

Comment: Hi KUMAR, I provide a workaround in the "Update" of my answer. Please check, maybe it will help your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, AD has not implemented this feature currently. If we use [microsoft graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), we can just do "[startwith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#encoding-query-parameters)" to filter the displayName of AD groups but can't do "contains" filter.

In this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0#examples) about powershell, the example2 shows us use this command `Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "All"` can get the groups that include the text "All" in their display names. But according to my test, it also do the filter "startwith" but not "contains".
[image]

So for this requirement, we can just get all of the groups by graph api and do the "contains" filter by self in our code. Or you can vote up for this feature on [feedback page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/37300951-support-contains-string-operator-in-odata-parame).

**Update:**

According to some test, I provide a workaround as below for your reference.

If we use powershell command, we can use the command below to implement the "contains":

```
Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object{($_.DisplayName -like '*test*')}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out piping where-object

Where-Object{($_.DisplayName -like '*test*')}